# Rails field enum as_json : get integer instead of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my projet, I have a User model with a gender enum :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   enum gender: [:female, :male]
end
```

When I'm calling `as_json` on one of my object, I get the string "female" or "male". Is there any way to render the integer value instead of the string ?

Comment: I just encountered this too... so Rails basically leaks a variable name into the data, bizarre

Answer (score -2):

I would try looking over the docs

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

for this, perhaps you could use a hash instead

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum gender: { female: 0, male: 1 }
end
```

hope its of any help

Comment: I still get the string value with `as_jon`

Comment: You use a hash to explicitly tell which value to maps to which entry. When you use array, their index is their value.

Answer (score -2):

`User.genders` is an array of your enum and integer value. So, use `User.genders[@user.gender].to_json`.

If you're not happy with the default, `to_json`, investigate [jBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) to create the exact JSON you

Comment: I'm not just calling the "gender" field. I'm doing this `@user.as_jon`